# while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file ... explanation

Tags: bash

I do not understand this line of shell script. Doesn't the while statement need a 'test' or [ ] or [[ ]] expression that will set $? to 1 or 0? How does

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do ...; done
```

do that? Any help understanding the syntax here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using `-d $'\0'` is misleading. Typically, `-d ''` is used instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Bash, `varname=value command` runs *command* with the environment variable `varname` set to `value` (and all other environment variables inherited normally). So `IFS= read -r -d $'\0'` runs the command `read -r -d $'\0'` with the environment variable `IFS` set to the empty string (meaning no field separators).

Since `read` returns success (i.e., sets `$?` to `0`) whenever it successfully reads input and doesn't encounter end-of-file, the overall effect is to loop over a set of NUL-separated records (saved in the variable `REPLY`).

> Doesn't the while statement need a 'test' or [ ] or [[ ]] expression that will set $? to 1 or 0?

`test` and `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` aren't actually *expressions*, but *commands*. In Bash, *every* command returns either success (setting `$?` to `0`) or failure (setting `$?` to a non-zero value, often `1`).

(By the way, as [nosid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305501/nosid) notes in a comment above, `-d $'\0'` is equivalent to `-d ''`. Bash variables are internally represented as C-style/NUL-terminated strings, so you can't really include a NUL in a string; e.g., `echo $'a\0b'` just prints `a`.)

Comment: I think the OP is also confused by the syntax of the `while` statement, not realising that arbitrary statements can be used.

Comment: @hvd: You may be right. I've expanded my answer a bit to address that directly.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not understand this line of shell script. Doesn't the while statement need a 'test' or [ ] or [[ ]] expression that will set $? to 1 or 0? How does [the statement] do that?

Everyone is answering about the `-d` and `IFS=` parameter, but no one answered your question about `test` and `[[..]]`.

All standard Unix commands will return a zero value on success and a non-zero value on exit. The `while` and `if` statements use that value to determine whether or not to continue to loop:

Let's say you do the following:

```
$ touch foo.txt   #Create a "foo.txt" file
$ ls foo.txt
foo.txt
$ echo $?
0
$
```

Notice that the `ls` command returned a zero on exit. Now try this:

```
$ rm foo.txt
$ ls foo.txt
ls: foo.txt: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
$
```

If `foo.txt` doesn't exist, the `ls` command returns a 1 on exit.

The `if` and `while` commands operate on that.

Go into another terminal window and create a `foo.txt` file. Then return to the original window and try this:

```
$ while ls foo.txt > /dev/null
> do
> echo "The file foo.txt exists"
> sleep 2
> done
The file foo.txt exists
The file foo.txt exists
The file foo.txt exists
...
```

Every two seconds, the while will loop through checking for the existence of `foo.txt` and print out that statement. Now, go back to the second terminal window and delete `foo.txt`. If you go back to the first terminal window, you'll see that the `while` loop ended.

You can do the same with the `if`:

```
$ if ls foo.txt > /dev/null
> then
>     echo "foo.txt exists"
> else
>     echo "Whoops, it's gone!"
> fi
```

This `if` statement will print either *foo.txt exists* or *Whoops, it's gone!* depending whether or not a file called `foo.txt` exists in the directory.

Notice that `if` and `while` work upon the ***return exit value*** of the command. There's no need for a test at all.

So why the `test`, `[...]`, and `[[...]]` syntax?

Let's say you want to find out whether `$foo` is equal to `$bar`. That's where `test` comes into play. Try this:

```
$ foo=42
$ bar=42
$ test "$foo" -eq "$bar"
$ echo $?
0
$ bar=0
$ test "$foo" -eq "$bar"
$ echo $?
1
```

All the test command does is return a zero on *true* tests and a non-zero value on *false* tests. This allows you to use the `test` command in `if` and `while` statements.

```
$ if test $foo -eq $bar
> then
>     echo "foo is equal to bar"
> else
>     echo "foo and bar are different"
> fi
foo and bar are different
$
```

So what's `[...]`?

```
$ ls -il /bin/test /bin/[
10958 -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  18576 May 28 22:27 /bin/[
10958 -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  18576 May 28 22:27 /bin/test
```

That first column is the *inode*. If two files have the same *inode*, they are *hard linked* and refer to the same file. Notice that they're both 18,576 bytes on my system.

The `[` is just another way to do the `test` command itself. Both of these lines are the same:

```
if test $foo -eq $bar
if [ $foo -eq $bar ]
```

The `[` was created to make shell scripts look a wee bit nicer. However, underneath, it's running a `test` command which will return either a zero or non-zero value that `if` and `while` can use.

By the way, in Kornshell and BASH, both `[` and `test` are *builtin* to the shell. But, they do reference the same *builtin* command.

The `[[...]]` is a special version of the test that first appeared in Kornshell. It allows for the use of pattern matches and it's a bit faster since it doesn't spawn another process to run the `test` command.

Comment: While `ls` is probably a good choice for demonstration purposes, using it in actual programs is usually a mistake.

Comment: @tripleee It was merely for demo purposes. `ls is an easy to understand command, and well known. If you want to know if a file exists, use `[ -f ... ]`.

Answer (score 3):

Code explanations :

- `IFS=` set IFS to null (input fiels separator)
- `read` command that reads the current line with the following options :
- `-r` : do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
- `-d` continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline
- `$'\0'` zero byte (the ASCII NUL character)

See

```
help read
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The `test` command and `[[ ...]]` expression are merely constructs that supply an exit status (the only thing `while` cares about) that reflects the truth of the conditional expression it contains.

For example, the exit status of `[[ $foo = bar ]]` is 0 (success) if `$foo` has the value `bar`, and a non-zero exist status (specifically 1) otherwise.

A `while` loop executes its body as long as the exit status of the command following the `while` keyword is 0. In this code, `read` has a 0 exit status as long as it can read something from its input.