# meaning of read and -d and $'\0' in bash

Tags: bash, syntax

What is the meaning of the following few syntaxes in bash following?
I do not understand what it does.

`while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file`

perhaps one can break this down so I can understand and change it for my need:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
dir_list=("${dir_list[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find a_directory_here -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

Comment: This `read` uses NUL character as delimiter. You can also use `-d ''`

Comment: thank you, it seems my question is duplicate. I found "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217930/while-ifs-read-r-d-0-file-explanation"

So, I will delete my question! the bash thing is killing me, the hardest thing ever!

Comment: The body of the loop is inefficient, you want just `dir_list+="$file"` (though we can speculate that having the results of `find` in an array is going to be unnecessary in many cases; do you really need this?)

Comment: Thank you @tripleee. does not matter even if it is unnecessary.

I have another question tho.

Do you have a guess what could be a problem when I make the `a_directory_here` shorter and increase these two `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`

it stops working, it is like it gets stuck in the `while` loop.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. Are you saying replace `while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file` with `while  read -d ''  $'\0' -r file`?

Comment: Yes that's right @NoLie

Comment: I don't understand the follow-up question. It doesn't belong in a comment anyway. Post another question with more details if you need help.

Comment: you wrote "making the value of `a_directory_here` shorter". So  you mean `find /usr/bin` vs `find /usr` and increase `-maxdepth=10` (or example)? ` The higher up the directory structure you go, the longer it will take to traverse all of the files and directories. On NFS mounted systems starting at `/` can easily take 1/2 hour or more to scan all files. Best to run a test outside of your `while` loop, that is just run `time find / -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 10` to understand how long to expect. (Change `/` as needed) ....

Comment: .... Note that the subsequent runs of a `find` command are often faster because some/most of the information is now in the system cache.